# Java types cannot be resolved to a type in Eclipse with JRE System Library included

Tags: java, eclipse

We have a legacy Java project which we are trying to get compiled within Eclipse. The project has been extracted from a live environment where it is working. A .JAR file within the lib folder has been reverse engineered using JD Decompiler and opened in Eclipse.

This has imported all the source code however it doesn’t build.  The errors are related to what seems to be missing primitive types. The kind of thing you would expect to find in the base Java System Library which we have included, for example:

- AbstractButton cannot be resolved to a type
- AbstractTableModel cannot be resolved to a type
- ActionEvent cannot be resolved to a type
- etc. with over 3000 errors of differing types.

The solution was written some decades ago against Java SE 1.1. We have therefore attempted to import both  historical system libraries around that time as well as more recent ones too including the latest Java SE 14.

We are importing these through the Configure Build Path window as a Library. I have added an ** allow all wildcard access rule to prevent any access errors which we were previously seeing.

We have also tried different libraries as both the Execution environment and Alternative JRE as well as trying the fix suggested in this YouTube video [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm3vP06NETY)

Can anyone suggest anything that we may be missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try with the same setup Lot of enhancements happened in java between 1.1 and 14.

Comment: Have tried with Installed JRE 1.1.3 which is the version that comments in the code state is the JD-Core Version. We then get the following 2 errors: The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.util.ArrayList. Fix the build path then try building this project AND Unknown Java Problem
The type java.util.ArrayList cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Comment: Does the JRE System Library node point to a valid JRE in your preferences?

Comment: ArrayList was added in Java 1.2

Comment: Thanks for replies. JRE is all setup in preferences. ArrayList was added in 1.2 however if I add the 1.2 library either on its own or along with the 1.1.3 library the error list on build returns to the 3000+ type errors talked about in the original post.

Comment: Anyone any more ideas? Unsure which version of JRE system library the project should be running. All that I have tried have resulted in problems. This is with using individual libraries and multiple ones at once.